# Pip error trying to get gphoto lib

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install the gphoto2 library for Python on a Raspberry Pi B+ 
and I get this error:

```
pi@mazePi:~ $  pip install gphoto2

Collecting gphoto2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/d7/7660013e81138c73232a62010d3d8816028d8a025d2e62c326dc07e9bb5f/gphoto2-1.8.2.tar.gz (7.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 7.2MB 12kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-kqalDU/gphoto2/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        cmd, stderr=FNULL, universal_newlines=True).split('.')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--modversion', 'libgphoto2']' returned non-zero exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-kqalDU/gphoto2/
```

When running in verbose mode, I get:

```
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-lLGQBj/gphoto2/setup.py) egg_info for package gphoto2
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    ERROR: command "pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2" failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-lLGQBj/gphoto2/setup.py", line 38, in <module>
        cmd, stderr=FNULL, universal_newlines=True).split('.')
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--modversion', 'libgphoto2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Cleaning up...
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lLGQBj/gphoto2/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 439, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 725, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lLGQBj/gphoto2/
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `apt list pkg-config` on your Pi?

Comment: pkg-config/stable,now 0.29-4 armhf [installed]

Comment: Hmm, okay, so `pkg-config` is indeed installed. Try running `pip install -v gphoto2` to see if the verbose output is helpful.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gidFjGN3

Comment: Nothing particularly different there. Did you install the `libgphoto2` headers? Check with `apt list libgphoto2-dev` - it should say `[installed]` if it is. (by the way, you can [edit] information into your question; no need to use Pastebin)

Comment: well it says: 
`code`Listing... Done
libgphoto2-dev/stable 2.5.12-1 armhf`code`

Comment: `>>> import gphoto2 as gp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import gphoto2 as gp
ImportError: No module named 'gphoto2'
>>> `

Comment: What is your operating system? On my raspi with default `Raspbian Stretch Lite` I get with `apt list gphoto2` the response `gphoto2/stable 2.5.11-1 armhf`. So why not simply install it from the default repository with `sudo apt install gphoto2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
Command '['pkg-config', '--modversion', 'libgphoto2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

indicates something went wrong when the script tried to run `pkg-config --modversion libgphoto2` on your system. As `apt list libgphoto2-dev` indicates that the headers are not installed (it doesn't say `[installed]` in the output), `pkg-config` fails to run properly when trying to link to libgphoto2. To install the headers, run:

```
sudo apt install libgphoto2-dev
```

This should resolve the issue and you should be able to re-run Pip successfully.